# Eclipse CDT build C++ project, how to use my own makefile for MacOS

Tags: macos, makefile, eclipse-cdt, gnu-make

I have a C++ project that I want to build using Eclipse CDT. I imported the project and make sure that "Auto generate make file" option is unchecked in the setting. In my project, I have multiple make files, the one I use for MACOS is called Makefile.darwin under project/src folder.

In terminal, I build the project by `make -f Makefile.darwin package` and then deploy it. I do have the target `all` and `package` in Makefile.darwin.

Under the `builder setting`, should I make the build directory to `${workspace_loc:/project-name}/` or `${workspace_loc:/project-name}/src`?
Could someone help me to build the file? I tried to make target to all, to package, but did not work. Where is the makefile located when I add a "make target"? I am so confused now.

Any ideas are really appreciated. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You should import your project with : new -> makefile project with existing code. Then you can tune make command (if necessary) from project setting.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I changed the builder settings to "clean all package" and then it magically compiled...